# Возможно ли заблокировать выгрузку вкладки из памяти браузера?

Tags: память, браузер, загрузка

Проблема такая. Разрабатываю браузерную игру. В ней важно, чтобы страница не перезагружалась, иначе уровень придётся начинать заново.

Я поймал противный баг, с которым понятия не имею, что делать. Дело было так: я на некоторое время отвлёкся и занимался другими делами. Когда я вернулся к игре и перешёл обратно на вкладку, то она перезагрузилась. Соответственно, стёрлось моё прохождение уровня.

Я предполагаю, что произошло это из-за того, что браузер автоматически выгружает из памяти вкладку, которая долго не использовалась. Возможно ли как-то запретить ему это делать?

Comment: Если браузер не будет освобождать память с неиспользуемых вкладок, вы не сможете открыть много вкладок. Для конкретной вкладки можно включить профилирование. Тогда она точно не будет выгружаться.

Comment: Не использовать Хром. Использовать Файрфокс.

Comment: Вряд ли возможно программным способом указать браузеру не перезагружать страницу. Это может сделать пользователь в настройках. А так, после каждого действия в игре сохраняйте её состояние в локальное хранилище.